# selection sort isn't sorting correctly

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

My selection sort algorithm isn't working correctly. I've been stuck on this for quite a long time. I've solved it using pointers but for some reason it's sorting incorrectly.

```
void sortArray(int arr[], size_t n)  
{  
    int i;  
    int j;
    int min_idx;  
    int min;  

    for (i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)  
    {  
        min = arr[i];
        min_idx = i;  
        for (j = (i+1); j < n - 1; j++)  
        {
            if (arr[j] < arr[min])  
            {
                min = arr[j];
                min_idx = j;
            }
        }   
        //swap(arr[min_idx], arr[i]);
        int temp = arr[min_idx];
        arr[min_idx] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;      
    } 
}
```

Before

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 0 0
```

After

```
0 9 7 3 6 4 5 8 10 0
```

But help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two bugs in the function.

The first one is that the last element of the array with the index `n-1` does not take part in sorting of the array due to conditions in the loops

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)  
{  
    min = arr[i];
    min_idx = i;  
    for (j = (i+1); j < n - 1; j++)  
    //..
```

The second bug is that in this if statement

```
if (arr[j] < arr[min])
```

there is used `min` as an index instead of `min_index` in the operand `arr[min]`.

Pay attention to that when `n` is equal to `0` or `1` then in the condition of the loop

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
```

the expression `n - 2` will yield a big unsigned value that results in undefined behavior of the function.

And these variables

```
int i;  
int j;
int min_idx;
```

shall have the type `size_t` instead of the type `int`.

Also declare variables in the minimum scope where they are used.

The function can be defined the following way.

```
void sortArray( int arr[], size_t n )  
{  
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )  
    {  
        size_t min_idx = i;  

        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )  
        {
            if ( arr[j] < arr[min_idx] )  
            {
                min_idx = j;
            }
        }   

        if ( i != min_idx )
        {
            int temp = arr[min_idx];
            arr[min_idx] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
        }      
    } 
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void sortArray( int arr[], size_t n )  
{  
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )  
    {  
        size_t min_idx = i;  

        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )  
        {
            if ( arr[j] < arr[min_idx] )  
            {
                min_idx = j;
            }
        }   

        if ( i != min_idx )
        {
            int temp = arr[min_idx];
            arr[min_idx] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
        }      
    } 
}

int main(void) 
{
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter the size of an integer array: " );

        size_t n = 0;

        if ( scanf( "%zu", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        int a[n];

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            a[i] = rand() % n;
        }

        printf( "Source array: " );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );

        sortArray( a, n );

        printf( "Sorted array: " );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter the size of an integer array: 10

Source array: 4 1 1 3 1 8 7 4 0 9 
Sorted array: 0 1 1 1 3 4 4 7 8 9 

Enter the size of an integer array: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner `if` is using the wrong index.  It should be

```
if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])
```

or, since `arr[min_idx]` is already stored in `min`

```
if (arr[j] < min)
```

You're also one index short in your sorting.  You never look at `arr[n - 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are three small errors.

Two off by one errors on your loop conditions, and one variable name error (`min` instead of `min_idx`).

Fixing these three errors gives us...

```c
void sortArray(int arr[], size_t n)  
{  
    int i;  
    int j;
    int min_idx;   

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)  
    {  
        min_idx = i;  
        for (j = (i+1); j < n; j++)  
        {
        if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])  
            {
            min_idx = j;
            }
        }   
        //swap(arr[min_idx], arr[i]);
        int temp = arr[min_idx];
        arr[min_idx] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;      
    } 
}
```

Also removed the unused `min` variable.